# add condition inside linq query

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements

I'm adding **accountRootTypes**    as param inside the query  if we keep it null it's returning 'Nullable object must have a value' how can I do the condition here

```
  public List<ReportHierarchyModel> GetReportBaseQuery(DateTimeOffset? dateFrom, DateTimeOffset? dateTo, List<AccountRootType> accountRootTypes = null)
    {
        var DbContext = this.DbContext as ICoreDbContext;


        var data = (
           from yy in DbContext.AccountTypes
           where (accountRootTypes != null ? (accountRootTypes.Any() ? accountRootTypes.Contains(yy.RootType) : true) : true)
           join ac2 in DbContext.AccountTypes on yy.Parent.Id equals ac2.Id into a2_join
           from _a2 in a2_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join xx in
           (
               from a in DbContext.Accounts
               join at in DbContext.AccountTypes on a.AccountSubType equals at  //right join
               from x in (
                  from j in DbContext.Journals
                  from je in j.Items //not cross-apply, relationship extrapolated from navigational property
                  where
                     je.Account == a && //outer apply
        (dateTo == null || j.Date.Date <= dateTo.Value.Date) &&
                     (dateFrom == null || j.Date.Date >= dateFrom.Value.Date)
                  select new
                  {
                      je.SignedBaseAmount
                  }
              )
               group  //available to select clause
               x.SignedBaseAmount
                   by new //group key
                   {
                       AccountId = a.Id,
                       AccountName = a.Name,
                       AccountUid = a.Uid,
                       AccountRootType = at.RootType,
                       AccountTypeId = at.Id,
                       AccountTypeName = at.Name,
                       AccountCode = a.Code,
                       ParentAccountId = a.Parent != null ? (int?)a.Parent.Id : null,
                       ParentAccountName = a.Parent != null ? a.Parent.Name : null,
                   }
                   into at_group
               orderby at_group.Key.AccountTypeId
               select new ReportHierarchyModel
               {
                   AccountId = (int?)at_group.Key.AccountId,
                   AccountName = at_group.Key.AccountName,
                   AccountUid = at_group.Key.AccountUid,
                   AccountCode = at_group.Key.AccountCode,
                   AccountRootType = at_group.Key.AccountRootType,
                   AccountTypeId = at_group.Key.AccountTypeId,
                   AccountTypeName = at_group.Key.AccountTypeName,
                   Amount = (decimal)at_group.Sum(x => x),
                   ParentAccountId = at_group.Key.ParentAccountId,
                   ParentAccountName = at_group.Key.ParentAccountName,
               }
           ) on yy.Id equals xx.AccountTypeId into xx_join
           from _xx in xx_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new ReportHierarchyModel()
           {
               TreeId = (int)yy.Id,
               ParentTreeId = yy.Parent.Id,
               AccountUid = _xx.AccountUid,
               AccountId = _xx.AccountId,
               AccountName = _xx.AccountName,
               AccountCode = _xx.AccountCode,
               AccountTypeId = yy.Id,
               AccountType = yy,
               AccountRootType = yy.RootType,
               BalanceType = yy.BalanceType,
               HierarchyLevel = yy.HierarchyLevel,
               Amount = (decimal)_xx.Amount,
               ParentAccountId = _xx.ParentAccountId,
               ParentAccountName = _xx.ParentAccountName,
           }
       ).ToList();

        return data;
    }
```

I need to add a condition for this param instead of creating 2 different functions one accountRootType and 1 without it. How can I create the condition in the query

Comment: try  `where accountRootTypes == null || accountRootTypes.Count == 0 || accountRootTypes.Contains(yy.RootType)`

Comment: `Nullable object must have a value` is usually when you call `.Value` on a `Nullable<T>`/`T?` value that doesn't have one. Are you sure `dateTo` isn't null?

Answer (score 0):

Probably EF Core fails to generate correct parameter accessor.
Split query into two parts, first query should prepare filter based on condition, second is original query:

```cs
var accountTypes = DbContext.AccountTypes.AsQueryable();
if (ccountRootTypes != null && accountRootTypes.Any())
    accountTypes = accountTypes.Where(at => accountRootTypes.Contains(at.RootType));

var data = (
    from yy in accountTypes
    join ac2 in DbContext.AccountTypes on yy.Parent.Id equals ac2.Id into a2_join
    ... // rest of the query
```